# Assets not copied to the dist folder in angular

Tags: angular

When running `ng build --prod`, the "assets" folder is not copied.

```
"root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
```

my environment

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 8.11.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.11
```

Thanks

Comment: Seems to be something related to certain symbols on folder names in your project path, would be good if you tell the path.

Comment: "C:\Projects\poladminUI\poladmin"

Answer (score -2):

```
use like below
"root": "./src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
```

Comment: if src root folder in your root directory than use "./src"

Comment: It appears the "assets" folder is empty, that's why it isn't copied

Comment: need to put assets folder in root src directory than try command.